# I am trying to performcalculation with multiple columns and assigning the value to a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign a column a value based on calculation from other columns. I want it to loop through all the rows and perform the same calculation. but nothing happens.

```
Sub calculateIncome()
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 2

  Dim counter As Integer
  counter = 2

  Dim j As Integer
  For j = 2 To i
    Worksheets("owssvr").Range("af" & j).Value = _
      Worksheets("owssvr").Range("v" & j).Value + Worksheets("owssvr").Range("y" & _
      j).Value + Worksheets("owssvr").Range("ab" & j).Value
    j= j + 1
  Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not going to loop because j "loops" from 2 to 2. What do you mean by "nothing happens"?

Comment: it doesn't perform the calculation

Comment: And what steps have you taken yourself to find out what is going on?

Comment: `Counter` is unnecessary. You're initializing it to `2`, the same as the start value of your `j` loop, then incrementing it by 1 each time through your loop, just like what it happening to `j` automatically. Use `j` instead of `counter`. Won't fix the problem, but will make your code a little easier to read.

Comment: i look at column "AF" to see if the values are assigned based on the calculation. But nothing is there, the calculation doesn't happen.

Comment: You should debug the code line by line to see if the code in the loop is executing.  Instead of just looking at the "AF" column to see if there is output.  That will let you know where the problem is located.

Comment: It's bad practise to alter the loop variable in a `For ...To` loop - that is already automatic: you don't need that `j=j+1`

Comment: I am new to VBA coding and i cant tell what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I can't see anything in that code that would disable the calculation. Perhaps you mean the result is not what you expect?

Comment: the result does not show. its blank

Comment: Is there any code after this block?

Comment: the code is in between Sub CalculateIncome() and End Sub

Comment: `i look at column "AF" to see if the values are assigned based on the calculation. But nothing is there, the calculation doesn't happen.` The code is only changing cell AF2 - are you 100% sure that cell is blank both before and after the calculation?  And do cells V2, Y2 and AB2 all contain numeric values?

Comment: It looks like you may have forgotten to put the subs in the question.

Comment: Yes, they all contain numeric values. The calculation works when i use the excel function V2+Y2+AB2

Comment: Include a `MsgBox "In loop"` as the line after `For j = 2 To i`.  Then set cell `owssvr!AF2` to some random value (i.e. just bash your fingers on the keyboard).  The run the macro. Does the `MsgBox` get displayed?  Does cell `owssvr!AF2` change back to being blank, or does it remain as it was?

Comment: I get a message box with the words "In Loop", but owssvr!AF2 is still blank

Comment: `is still blank` - do you mean that it changed from being the random info you put into it back to being blank?   You don't have any `Worksheet_Change` event on this sheet do you?

Comment: oh no, it had the random info i put in.

Comment: OK, change the `MsgBox "In loop"` to be `MsgBox "|" & Worksheets("owssvr").Range("af" & j).value & "|"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to do this:

```
Sub calculateIncome()
    Dim startLine As Integer
    Dim endLine As Integer
    Dim currentLine As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    startLine = 2 ' you must preset
    endLine = 126 ' you must preset
    Set ws = Worksheets("owssvr")
    For currentLine = startLine To endLine
        ws.Range("af" & currentLine).Value = _
            ws.Range("v" & currentLine).Value + _
            ws.Range("y" & currentLine).Value + _
            ws.Range("ab" & currentLine).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

But, erm, why not type `=V2+Y2+AB2` in cell `AF2` and then copy the formula all the way down your list?

Comment: Much as I prefer your version of the code, it doesn't really explain why the OP's code is not updating cell AF2, so I suspect that whatever is causing their code to not update that cell will also cause your code to not update it.  (But, who knows, maybe if they just use your code their problem will go away - I am always suspicious of code which doesn't look as if it has been copied from the VBE, such as the OP's `.value` [with a lower-case `v`] and `j= j+ 1` [with missing spaces].)

Comment: @YowE3K, OP's could should update only line 2, because the for...loop is set to loop from 2 to i... which is 2. It will be a single loop. I suspect when OP says "nothing happens", it's because he doesn't get the intended full iteration.

Comment: No, if you read the comments, even cell AF2 isn't updating - even though it is getting into the loop.  So I am really confused as to what is causing the issue.  (P.S.  My concern about the lower-case `v` in `value` seems to be unfounded - that was changed by someone editing the question.)

Comment: @YowE3K, you are right. Sorry. But then he says that the test you suggested worked - "oh no, it had the random info i put in" - which makes me, erm, regain my suspicion. Anyway, if that code doesn't throw an exception, then there's nothing preventing it to work. But then, again, it ocurred to me now that if V2, Y2 and AB2 are empty/blank strings, the result would be exactly that described by OP. I can speculate no further without having the very workbook in hands.

Comment: The fact that the random info was still in the cell means that the OP's `Worksheets("owssvr").Range("af" & j).value = ...` didn't work, despite the `MsgBox` being displayed.  And I thought about the `"" + "" + ""` scenario, but the OP confirmed that the values were numbers.  I am stumped (but guessing that there is either a `Change` event setting the value back to the previous value, or that the OP is looking at the wrong sheet).  Unfortunately, it appears the OP has gone away for awhile, so I may have to wait for some time to satisfy my curiosity as to what **is** the problem. :(

Comment: @YowE3K, yes, you are right, and I misread those comments again. Shame on me... Let's wait then.

Comment: Ok. so I tried the code with a sample data similar to the actual worksheet. The code works and calculate the three columns(A,B,C) that I tested with and the value is in the column D. However, the calculation doesn't paste the values starting from D2. it starts from D22 and then skips more rows and continues on D210. and on the rows in Columns A,B,C that has no values inside, the total is calculated as 0. I uploaded a snapshot of how it looked after running the code.

Comment: I will go the easy way route and use "=v2+y2+AB2" in cell AF2. and use VBA code to auto fill the formula down to the last row.

Comment: @Richmond In your test code, did it happen to update cells D22, D23 ... D29, before jumping to D210?  That could be explained by using `"D2" & j` instead of `"D" & j`.

Comment: Yes, it did update D22, D23 ... D31 and jumped to D210

Comment: @Richmond If it updated D31 then my thought of `"D2" & j` won't be the reason for the jump.

Comment: @Richmond I was just reviewing some suggested edits and came across one where you were trying to edit VBobCat's answer by including a screenshot (that should be in your question, not in this answer).  I notice in the screenshot that D31 was **not** updated - that it was only updating cells D22, D23 ... D29, before jumping to D210 - so I will go back to believing that you used `"D2" & j` instead of `"D" & j`.

Comment: @Richmond, could you share your workbook with us? You could strip out all the sensitive information. I think it will be of great help in this case.

Comment: @VBobCat and YowE3K I really appreciate the help you guys put into this. I was able to make it work with the comment suggestions and the codes suggested. I have one more task to do which i don't know how to approach it. I have a list of names in Column A, and on the same sheet i have a button that generate a PDF report for each name i select in column A. I want to automate the process of selecting names one by one from column A and clicking on the button to generate the PDF. So i am looking for a VBA code that will loop through the names in column A and perform the Click button.

Comment: @Richmond, as for your PDF automation, the algorithm would be much like this, but instead of setting a cell's value, you'd perform the operations involved with pdf generation, like [selecting the desired cell](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291308/how-to-select-cells-ranges-by-using-visual-basic-procedures-in-excel) and programatically calling the same sub that handles your button's click event. Should you have difficulties, however, you ought to post a new question with all details and code involved.

Comment: Consider also accepting my answer and upvoting the comments made by @YowE3K